# Error Crystal report hide all Space character

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2008

I faced an issue like that:  When I running source aspx in Local machine and export Report by crystal report, everything look good. but when publish this source to Server, this report export pdf has Hidden all space charracter like this:
[image]

All space look like hidden and can see somthing like dot character below each space hidden.
Anyone know this issue please give me a help.
Thanks.
p/s: I using Microsoft visual studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

Check font permissions for user context of the server process.

Also, does the font you use on the server include embeddability permissions?
You can check that via properties of the font.

Comment: I check it already, nothing difference. another report using same font and dont happen this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open the two reports (the good one and the bad one) in Crystal Designer. Go to File, Page Setup...
Compare the printer assigned.  Most likely the bad report is assigned a bad printer (doesn't exist on the server, bad driver, or some other problem).